# Google-Colaboratory - How to Refresh google-drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory, mount, drive

I am using google-colaboratory GPU to train NN models.
My python/pytorch code is stored in google-drive.
I am able to mount my drive in colaboratory  and train models.
But any python code changes in the "my drive"  is not updated to google-colaboratory even after rebooting my PC and start all again.

To clear the google-colaboratory cache I tried :

```
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -cc
```

But it does not work:

```
/bin/bash: google-drive-ocamlfuse: command not found
```

How to clean this cache and avoid waiting hours before my code being taken into account by google-colaboratory ? Thanks in advance

PS : the method I used to mount:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Comment: Are the changes reflected in the Drive web UI? What program are you using to synchronize your Drive files to your PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`google-drive-ocamlfuse` is irrelevant to mounts using `google.colab.drive.mount` as described in the PS, so not surprising the -cc invocation is not helping you.
I suspect what's happening is you have `.py` files stored in Google Drive, which you're `import`ing in your notebook, and you want to see changes to the `.py` files reflected in your runtime, but they're not because python's `import` system is idempotent (an `import` statement is ignored if python thinks it's already loaded a module by that name, even if the underlying file has changed). 
You can force a reload using something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/8755609 e.g.:

```
from importlib import reload  # Py3 only; unneeded in py2.
foo = reload(foo)
```

(obvs replace `foo` with your module's name).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Ami. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive/',force_remount=True)
```

Sometimes the files tab lags behind in refreshing so you might consider waiting for some time too.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to how Drive FileStream works on Windows/MACOS

1. Unmount the drive

```sh
fusermount -u /content/drive
```

2. Clear the Drive content_cache folder

```sh
rm -rf /root/.config/Google/DriveFS/<UNIQUE NUMERICAL ID>/content_cache
```

3. Remount using drive.mount()